# Filtering Table Row by Text found in Cell then Filter those Rows by text found in remaining Cells

Tags: javascript, html, filter, html-table

Based on W3C tutorial (Filter/Search Table) I have a table with two relevant columns in each row, which I want to filter using two Select Menus.

The first Select Menu chooses which rows to display **sortByColor()** based on the text value in the first cell, which works fine. I then want the other Select Menu to refine the filter further **sortBySize()**, by displaying the current visible rows that contain a text value in the third column.

This second function undoes the first select menu function and unhides all the other rows that also have the text value in the third column... I have tried making the first function **sortByColor()** fire within the **sortBySize()** function but that stops sortBySize from working at all.

I expected that to find the rows with the text value, then hide the ones not currently selected in the first Select Menu, basically running the first function **sortByColor()** again.

```js
function sortByColor() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValueC;
  input = document.getElementById("byColor");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("MainTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValueC = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValueC.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].className = "isVisible";
      } else {
        tr[i].className = "notVisible";
      }
    }       
  }
}
        
function sortBySize() {
    
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValueT;
  input = document.getElementById("bySize");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("MainTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (td) {
      txtValueT = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValueT.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].className = "isVisible";
      } else {
        tr[i].className = "notVisible";
      }
    }      
  } 
}
```

```css
.notVisible{ display: none; }
```

```html
     <select id="byColor"  onchange="sortByColor();"  value="0">
    <option value="">Filter by Color</option>  
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
    
<select id="bySize"  onchange="sortBySize();">
    <option value="0">Filter by Size</option>
    <option value="XSmall">X Small</option>
    <option value="Small">Small</option>
    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="Large">Large</option>
    <option value="XLarge">X Large</option>
</select>

<table width="100%" border="0" id="MainTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Design 1</td>
      <td>XSmall, Medium, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Design 2</td>
      <td>Small, Medium, Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Design 3</td>
      <td>Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Design 4</td>
      <td>XSmall, Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>Design 1</td>
      <td>XSmall, Medium, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>Design 2</td>
      <td>Small, Medium, Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>Design 3</td>
      <td>Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>Design 4</td>
      <td>XSmall, Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Design 1</td>
      <td>XSmall, Medium, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Design 2</td>
      <td>Small, Medium, Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Design 3</td>
      <td>Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Design 4</td>
      <td>XSmall, Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td>Design 1</td>
      <td>XSmall, Medium, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td>Design 2</td>
      <td>Small, Medium, Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td>Design 3</td>
      <td>Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td>Design 4</td>
      <td>XSmall, Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Design 1</td>
      <td>XSmall, Medium, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Design 2</td>
      <td>Small, Medium, Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Design 3</td>
      <td>Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Design 4</td>
      <td>XSmall, Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone shed a little light on a solution to make this work? Thanks.

**[jsfiddle: Table Filter by Two Variables](https://jsfiddle.net/JWWright/qn53yxmf/23/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can not do this in 2 different functions.
It can be done with one.

```js
function sort() {
  var inputColor, filterColor, txtValueColor, inputSize, filterSize, txtValueSize, table, tr, td, i;
  inputColor = document.getElementById("byColor");
  filterColor = inputColor.value.toUpperCase();
  inputSize = document.getElementById("bySize");
  filterSize = inputSize.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("MainTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    txtValueColor = td && (td.textContent || td.innerText);
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    txtValueSize = td && (td.textContent || td.innerText);
    if (txtValueColor.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterColor) > -1 &&
        txtValueSize.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterSize) > -1) {
      tr[i].className = "isVisible";
    } else {
      tr[i].className = "notVisible";
    }      
  }
}
```

```css
.notVisible{ display: none; }
```

```html
<select id="byColor"  onchange="sort();"  value="0">
    <option value="">Filter by Color</option>  
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
    
<select id="bySize"  onchange="sort();">
    <option value="">Filter by Size</option>
    <option value="XSmall">X Small</option>
    <option value="Small">Small</option>
    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="Large">Large</option>
    <option value="XLarge">X Large</option>
</select>

<table width="100%" border="0" id="MainTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Design 1</td>
      <td>XSmall, Medium, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Design 2</td>
      <td>Small, Medium, Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Design 3</td>
      <td>Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Design 4</td>
      <td>XSmall, Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>Design 1</td>
      <td>XSmall, Medium, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>Design 2</td>
      <td>Small, Medium, Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>Design 3</td>
      <td>Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>Design 4</td>
      <td>XSmall, Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Design 1</td>
      <td>XSmall, Medium, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Design 2</td>
      <td>Small, Medium, Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Design 3</td>
      <td>Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Design 4</td>
      <td>XSmall, Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td>Design 1</td>
      <td>XSmall, Medium, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td>Design 2</td>
      <td>Small, Medium, Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td>Design 3</td>
      <td>Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td>Design 4</td>
      <td>XSmall, Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Design 1</td>
      <td>XSmall, Medium, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Design 2</td>
      <td>Small, Medium, Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Design 3</td>
      <td>Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Design 4</td>
      <td>XSmall, Large, XLarge</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```